# Javascript: Validate radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a group of two sex radio buttons, but am getting an error.
I have the following:

It is giving an error on itm.length; says it is undefined.

```js
function validateSex(itm, elmt) {
 var dom = document.getElementById(elmt);
 var numChecked = 0;

 for (var index = 0; index < itm.length; index++) {
   if (itm[index].checked) {
     numChecked++;
     break;
    }
 }

 // if sex not selected display error message.
 if (numChecked === 0) {
  dom.innerHTML = "Please select the sex.";
  return false;
 }else {
  dom.innerHTML = "";
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type = "radio" name = "sex" value= "male"
    title = "Select sex" 
    onchange = "validateSex(this, 'msgSex')"/>Male
   <input type = "radio" name = "sex" value= "female"
    title = "Select sex" 
    onchange = "validateSex(this, 'msgSex')"/>Female
  </td>
  
  <td id = "msgSex"></td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: make JSFiddle for more understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementsByName('sex')` instead of `this` in `validateSex(this, 'msgSex')` if you need the length attribute.
But you can't validate radio button like this.